# Kotlin/Native framework with platform libs

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I have a Kotlin/Native project, which compiles to an iOS framework and an Android library.
I'd like to use POSIX from the `platform.posix.` in the unit tests of the project, but the compiler can't find the `platform` package.

I have tried importing it like this: `import platform.posix.*`

I have looked at this README.md from the kotlin-native repository: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/PLATFORM_LIBS.md

It says:

> The packages from platform libraries are available by default. No
>   special link flags need to be specified to use them. Kotlin/Native
>   compiler automatically detects which of the platform libraries have
>   been accessed and automatically links the needed libraries.

I am a bit confused - what am I missing to make the compiler discover the platform libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On JVM Android `platform.posix` is not available, it is pure Kotlin/Native feature.

Comment: That makes sense. I also discovered that I did not need to use the `platform.posix` after all, since I am allowed to rely on `java.io` in my unit tests, since they are on the JVM. Thanks!